# Power BI streaming (push) dataset: How to filter for *today*, without calculated columns?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

The usual way to filter a power bi visual or report to just the current day is to add a calculated column to the model with dax using the TODAY() function, and filter on that. Typical example:

```
TodayQ = IF(Table1[Date]=TODAY(),1,0)
```

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Filter-by-today-s-date/td-p/150039

With streaming push datasets, calculated columns are not available. So what's another approach to achieve a live dashboard always being filtered to the current day?

Answer (score 0):

You can try applying the time filter in the Visual Level filter using "Relative date filtering" in filter type, select in Show items when the value "is in this" int the first drop down box and "day" in the second drop down and then apply filter.